# Is $a b^T$ + $b a^T$ positive semidefinite if $a^T b > 0$

Tags: vectors, positive-semidefinite

Let $a$ and $b$ are $m \times 1$ constant vectors such that  $a^T b > 0$. I am wondering if the matrix $a  b^T$+$b  a^T$ is positive semidefinite. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks. ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can make up plenty of examples. You want vectors $a,b,x$ so that, for example, $a\cdot b > 0$, $a\cdot x>0$ and $b\cdot x<0$. Then $(ab^\top + ba^\top)x\cdot x = 2(a\cdot x)(b\cdot x)$ will be negative. For example:
$$a=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad b=\begin{bmatrix} -2\\3 \end{bmatrix}, \quad x=\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$
should yield $(ab^\top+ba^\top)x\cdot x = -42$.

Comment: Many thanks for the counter example.

Comment: You should try experimenting yourself before posting, in the future. :) These days people will move to close your question for no effort, and I will get negative votes for answering you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can I have one more question? Under what conditions the matrix $a b^T$ will be p.s.d? Thanks

Comment: Only when $b$ is a positive scalar multiple of $a$. Consider the formula in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!